# Run a scheduler to check if batch is finished and apply calculations for every finished batch in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have the following data which I randomally generated in kusto.

```
 let data = datatable(BatchNumber: int,Timestamp:datetime, Power1:int, Power2: int, Speed1: int, Speed2: int, Enabled1: bool, Enabled2: bool)
        [
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:00:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:01:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:02:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:03:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:04:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:05:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:06:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:07:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:08:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:09:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:10:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:11:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:12:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:13:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:14:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true,
         2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
        ];
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to check when is the batch finished. **The logic to do that is to get the last value of a batch number and check the value after it. If the next value is different from the one before then the previous batch is finished**. So in this case, batch number = 1 is finished but batch number 2 not yet. However, in this case I shouldn't be checking for a specific batch number because we are getting values in real time. The script should know by itself when is the batch finished probably by doing a scheduler which runs every 5 minutes to check if the batch is finished based on the logic I explained above (in bold), and when it knows that the batch is finished, it should project this batch number, Batch_Date (in this case for batch number = 1, the date is 2022-02-18 10:07:00 AM), and total power (which is based on some calculations only for this finished batch)

For example expected result for BatchNumber = 1:

[image]

In this case, once the script knows that batch number 2 is also finished a new record will be added with this batch number. Let us assume that one addition row was added to the dataset with batch number = 3, so the expected result would be:

[image]

So everytime the script knows that a batch is finished it should directly add it as a new record as shown in the screenshots, projecting the new batch, the date when it was finished and some calculations specifically for newly added batch.

I am a bit confused how can I do this in Kusto? If it is possible or not ? I don't know if a scheduler is needed in this case or if there is a better and efficient way to do it?

Comment: (1) Seems like faulty logic. A batch can be stuck forever like this. At minimum you should define the max duration for an open batch. (2) The fact that you need to query your logs in order to understand which batch was closed might indicate an issue with the data architecture.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Thank you for your answer. What do you suggest doing in this case ? How can I proceed and can you please explain why would the batch be stuck forever (probably if no other batch was used after right ?). The problem is that there is no other way to do it I guess

Comment: (1) Yes, you got it. (2) Since these logs are being generated somehow, whatever generates them can also indicate a new batch generation and probably also the ending of a one, (3) Is `Batch` an increasing number?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Thank you for your answer. Yes the Batch is an increasing number as shown in the example above. Is there a possibility to create a script in this case which does the logic above. If yes, can you please show me how you apply it in Kusto ? (Ignoring the fact that the batch might be stuck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is reporting, we leverage [materialized views](https://materialized-view)

##### Demo

```
.create table data (BatchNumber: int,Timestamp:datetime, Power1:int, Power2: int, Speed1: int, Speed2: int, Enabled1: bool, Enabled2: bool)
```

---

```
.create-or-alter materialized-view data_mv on table data
{
    data
    | summarize BatchData = max(Timestamp), TotalPower = sum(coalesce(Power1,0) + coalesce(Power2,0)) by BatchNumber
}
```

---

```
.create-or-alter materialized-view data_max_BatchNumber_mv on table data
{
    data
    | summarize BatchNumber = max(BatchNumber) by dummy = 1
}
```

---

```
.create-or-alter function completed_batches_f ()
{
    let max_BatchNumber = toscalar(data_max_BatchNumber_mv | project BatchNumber);
    data_mv
    | where BatchNumber < max_BatchNumber
}
```

---

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:00:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:01:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:02:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:03:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:04:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |

---

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:05:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:06:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
1, datetime(2022-02-18 10:07:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:08:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:09:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:10:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:11:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-18T10:07:00Z | 2400 |

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:12:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:13:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:14:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, true, true
2, datetime(2022-02-18 10:15:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-18T10:07:00Z | 2400 |

---

```
.ingest inline into table data <|
3, datetime(2022-02-18 10:16:00 AM), 100, 200, 50, 80, false, true
```

---

```
completed_batches_f
```

| BatchNumber | BatchData | TotalPower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-18T10:07:00Z | 2400 |
| 2 | 2022-02-18T10:15:00Z | 2700 |

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Just one question, assuming that the batch number is unique (and not an increasing number but a string instead of number let us say for example first batch number = 1254X second one is named completely different. How can we adapt the code above to such situation ?

Comment: Yes sorry about that. The answer ofcourse has been accepted. Thank you so much for your help. I should have modified the description and data sample with this unique batch number that could be a string. I will open a new post just with a different description (where the batch number is unique and not an increasing number) so most probably the code that you provided here will be a bit different. Is it possible to mention you in the new post ?

Comment: Sure, please do